# how do i display an alert box after inserting records into the database using javascript and php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

The code below is able to insert into the database but doesn't display anything.

I tried playing around with the code using JavaScript and AJAX though I only have basic understanding of the two and wasn't able to change anything.

I am a beginner and any help will be appreciated.

```
<?php
 require_once 'connect.php';
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
 {
    {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO message (Names, Email, Numbers,Message)
        VALUES ('$name','$email','$phone','$message')";
        echo"Record Enterd";

        if ($conn->query($sql) === true) {

        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }

    }


 }
 ?>
```

Comment: What you've tried for alert message after inserting the record

Comment: This article has some good examples of how PHP can interact with HTML nad JavaScript to generate web content: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php

Comment: if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert(Message Successfully Sent !!);</script>";
   } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
   }

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because user data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.

Comment: Do try and get out of the habit of cluttering up your code with needless things like `=== true`. Many functions are designed to return values that evaluate as logically true or false so that's redundant.

Comment: Hint: When writing JavaScript inside of PHP it still needs to be valid JavaScript. That wouldn't work if inside a plain HTML file. When debugging JavaScript problems **always** check your JavaScript console for errors.

Comment: @tadman, How do i remove the SQL injection bugs? what changes can i make to my code? i can share the form code if you want just to show you what am working on.

Comment: My comment addresses that quite specifically: **Use prepared statements with placeholder values**. I'm not sure what database driver you're using here, so unless you can better explain, I can't give more specific advice.

Comment: I am using XAMPP

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === true) {
        ?>
    <script type="text/javascript"> alert('data submitted successfully'); </script>
    <?php
                } else {
                    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
                }
```

Comment: it worked though i have another question,is it possible for the alert box to display in the same browser window?

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
echo "<script>alert('Record Added Successfully')</script>";
```